# Connecting separately powered devices via serial

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, logic-level

I have a small issue connecting an FTDI USB to 5V Serial adapter to an externally powered PIC microcontroller. They are connected via serial connection. The USB connection powered the FTDI and a battery powers the PIC.

```
                 Serial
Laptop --- FTDI ======== PIC ----- 3.7V battery
```

Currently I have 4k7 resistors in the serial lines. 5V high on the FTDI's TX will be clamped to whatever the PIC is (3v - 4.2v) via the input protection diodes, and 3V from the PIC's TX is higher than the FTDI's input threshold. This seems ok, limiting the protection diode current to 500uA.

My main concern is unplugging the cable from the laptop. Then the FTDI device is powered off and the PIC, via its TX line, will try and power it. Even at 10K, that's 500uA. I've no idea if that's a bad idea or not.

I've a feeling this isn't the best way of going about this given that either circuit could be powered off and damaged by the other. Would it be better to convert each RX side into a pseudo "open drain"?

```
              +----- Vdd
             100k
+-------|<----+------RX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can answer this one myself. My main issue was knowing whether or not 500uA flowing into the FTDI chip will damage it but I think the best idea is to avoid having to ask that question.

If I use a voltage divider from the main USB line to an analog comparator or a2d or even a high value pullup to a logic input on the PIC micro, then I can detect if USB power is present or not. If not I can tristate the serial port.

Other than that, googling reveals that using the diode and pull up to RX works just fine to prevent current flowing the wrong way...

Comment: Except it doesn't. Current can flow from Vdd, through the 100k resistor and the diode and into the other circuit. The only way is double FET isolation - two N fets connected drain to drain as per section 2.3.5 of an older Philips app note (http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf)